# Label is hidden under circle background colour

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, drawrect

I have just added a background to my circular progress bar, however this background now covers a label that I have in the centre of the circle.

Basically, I have a a background circle, a radius (for displaying the progress) and a label which is right in the centre of the circle. Having now added the circle background means that the label is covered.

Here is my code:

```
class ProgressCircle: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    var innerRadiusRatio: CGFloat = 0.6

    var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var startAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2)
    var endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + min(1.0, progress) * CGFloat(M_PI * 2)
    var outerRadius: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5 - 1.0
    var innerRadius: CGFloat = outerRadius * innerRadiusRatio
    var center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))

    //Code for background circle

    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, (UIColor.darkGrayColor()).CGColor)
    var rectangle: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 171, 171)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Code for progress radius

    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, center.x, center.y, outerRadius, endAngle, startAngle, true)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path)

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFill").CGImage)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
```

This is how I add the subview:

```
    var circleFrame = CGRect(x: 75, y: 249, width: 171, height: 171)
    var circle = ProgressCircle(frame: circleFrame)
    self.budgetDisplayView.addSubview(circle)

    circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

How can I get the label to be displayed on top of the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your subviews.

If you added your `ProgressCircle` view in Interface Builder, then in the Document Outline in Xcode, drag your label view down below your `ProgressCircle` view.  The subviews are added in order, so the later ones are on top.

If you added your `ProgressCircle` in code, in your `ViewController` after adding the `subView`, call `sendSubviewToBack` to move the `ProgressCircle` behind its siblings:

```
self.budgetDisplayView.addSubview(circle)
self.budgetDisplayView.sendSubviewToBack(circle)
```

Alternatively, if you have an `@IBOutlet` to your label called `myLabel`, you can bring it to front:

```
self.budgetDisplayView.bringSubviewToFront(myLabel)
```

Finally, make sure your label has a color that will show against the background.

Comment: I don't have a ProgressCircle view. I just added it in code.

Comment: Did that work?  How is your label added?  Is it a subview of `budgetDisplayView` as well?

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The label was added via storyboard. I've tried using the code you suggested while also moving the label right to the front, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is your label a `subview` of `budgetDisplayView`?

Comment: Do you have an `@IBOutlet` for your label?  If so: `budgetDisplayView.bringSubviewToFront(myLabel)` after adding your progressCircle.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot! I actually tried doing that after you suggested moving the circle to the back, and it didn't work but it was because the text was the same colour as the circle background.

Comment: Ha ha.  That was my next question.  Is your text a color that will show against the background.